# Native compile spring boot 3 with log4j2 java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.logging.log4j.message.DefaultFlowMessageFactory.<init>()

Tags: spring-boot, log4j2, graalvm

When I compile a spring boot 3 application to native image using the plugin, e.g:

```bash
./gradlew bootBuildImage --imageName=example.com/library/my-app:v1
```

and then run it:

```
docker run --rm -p 5050:5050 example.com/library/my-app:v1
```

If I use Spring Boot 3.0.8 I don't get any issue, but if I switch to 3.1.0 or 3.1.1 I get this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jMarkerFactory.<clinit>(Log4jMarkerFactory.java:36)
        at org.apache.logging.slf4j.SLF4JServiceProvider.initialize(SLF4JServiceProvider.java:53)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:183)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:170)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getProvider(LoggerFactory.java:455)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:441)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:390)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:416)
        at com.example.messaging.Application.<clinit>(Application.java:13)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.InstantiationException: org.apache.logging.log4j.message.DefaultFlowMessageFactory
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.createDefaultFlowMessageFactory(AbstractLogger.java:242)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.<init>(AbstractLogger.java:141)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.status.StatusLogger.<init>(StatusLogger.java:141)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.status.StatusLogger.<clinit>(StatusLogger.java:91)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: org.apache.logging.log4j.message.DefaultFlowMessageFactory
        at java.base@17.0.7/java.lang.Class.newInstance(DynamicHub.java:639)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.createDefaultFlowMessageFactory(AbstractLogger.java:240)
        ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.logging.log4j.message.DefaultFlowMessageFactory.<init>()
        at java.base@17.0.7/java.lang.Class.checkMethod(DynamicHub.java:1040)
        at java.base@17.0.7/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(DynamicHub.java:1206)
        at java.base@17.0.7/java.lang.Class.newInstance(DynamicHub.java:626)
        ... 13 more
```

It suggests that DefaultFlowMessageFactory doesn't have a default constructor, but looking at the source code it's there.

Any idea what might been causing this?

I've looked at this [issue](https://github.com/oracle/graal/issues/5683) but was not helpful.

Comment: this looks like dependency version mismatch(probably you are giving a version for log4j  which is not compatible with 3.1), can you share your build.gradle ?

Comment: The version is managed by spring boot bom (implementation platform("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:${springBootVersion}")). Then no version is used: implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2"). Following https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-dependencies/3.1.1 I noticed that log4j2 had a version minor bump.

Answer (score 3):

Log4J2 is NOT supported yet in native image, see [SB issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/37152) and [SB Wiki](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-with-GraalVM#logging), look like the only option is to switch to logback.